# Presenting a modal view using a Wireframe/Router entity

Tags: ios, swift, mvp, clean-architecture

My question is: having a Wireframe entity, a modal view should be presented by the wireframe using a Presenter entity or due to having a vertical hierarchy it should be presented directly by the parent view controller?

A:

```
parentVC.presenter?.presentModalView()//This method call the wireframe routing
```

B:

```
parentVC.present(ModalView())
```

Which is the correct option? I think that B is the best approach due to the fact that a modal view is part of the functionality of a parent VC; is not another module.